Confusion about the definition of strict epimorphism
I'm trying to decipher the definition of strict epimorphism given here. What does $f : B → C$ is a strict epimorphism if it is the colimit of the (possibly large) diagram consisting of all parallel pairs $g , h : A ⇉ B$ such that $f \circ g = f \circ h$ mean?
I have come to think that it says that given a category $C$, and a morphism $f$, $f$ is a strict epimorphism if $\{(f,f)\}_{j \in J}$ is the colimit of a diagram $F: J \rightarrow C \times C$, whose image consists of all pairs $(d,e)$ such that $f \circ d = f\circ e$; however, that would imply that all such a pairs have the same domain of $f$, which is not true in general.
I'm really confused about this definition.
Any help would be appreciated.

The intended diagram is obtained as follows. First consider all triples $(A,g,h)$ where $g$ and $h$ are morphisms $A\to B$ and $f\circ g=f\circ h$. For each such triple, put a vertex in your diagram labeled with the object $A$. Also, put in a special vertex labeled with $B$. Then, for each triple $(A,g,h)$ as above, add two arrows from its vertex (labeled $A$) to the special vertex; label those two arrows $g$ and $h$. That's the diagram you want.
Notice that the requirement $f\circ g=f\circ h$ in our triples ensures that there is a cocone from this diagram to $C$.  It consists of $f$ as the morphism from the special vertex to $C$, and all its other morphisms are then determined (by the commutativity requirements for a cocone).
Notice also that the subdiagram consisting of just a single $(A,g,h)$ vertex, the special vertex, and the two morphisms between them is the diagram whose colimit defines the coequalizer of $g$ and $h$. Since the whole diagram consists of many such subdiagrams (joined together at the special vertex), some people (including me) would call $f$ the simultaneous coequalizer of all those $(g,h)$ pairs.

Is the special vertex the triple $(B, f,f)$?

The special vertex does not correspond to any triple, it's just a separate point labeled $B$. (Really, it doesn't matter what the vertex is, but rather what its relationship with the others is: think structurally.)

Concretely, the definition means: if $u:B \to T$ is a morphism that coequalizes every pair $g,h:A \to B$ that is coequalized by $f$, then $u$ factors uniquely through $f$. So in formulas:
$$(\forall g,h : fg=fh \implies ug=uh) \implies \exists! v (u=vf)$$
If this holds for all $u$, then $f$ is a strong epi.
Notice that the assumption on the left here is the "bare minimum" we need to require for a morphism that factors through $f$. In case of a strong epi this is already enough. This makes it, well, strong.
